# Running a binary as systemd service does not work

Tags: go, systemd, systemctl

I have a go project and when I compile it I get your typical binary. If I call the binary directly from the command line with the adequate inputs, it runs perfectly well. I want to make this program part of the systemd ecosystem and the following is my my `gobinary.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Go Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/directory/
ExecStart=/path/to/directory/binary --config config/service.conf
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start and stop the service using the usual `sudo service gobinary start` without error messages but the problem is that the program is actually not running because it does not respond to the inputs, namely it has a rabbitmq input queue, despite me sending content to the queue it doesn't react. If however I run the program using the binary directly `$ ./binary --config/service.conf` everything runs smoothly. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl -f` and watch for error messages related to your binary.

Comment: No error messages.

Comment: Watch out for proper "exec type" in the unit config: the default is not what you want. You need to set it to "simple" or "nofork" or something like this (can't check ATM).

Comment: Per documentation, the default should be simple.

Comment: Doesn't your program log anything?

Comment: @kostix `Type=simple` is the default, so it's fine to omit this for a service which remains in foreground.

Comment: Try `ExecStart=/path/to/directory/binary --config /full/path/to/config/service.conf`

Comment: Yes, that is actually how my systemd calls for the config file (whole path) but it still does not work.